# Spring data redis - actual TTL not retrieve with @TimeToLive

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

### Recovering real time via an annotated property with @TimeToLive

Hello, I'm using the version of **spring-boot-starter-data-redis 3.1.7**

I saw that there was already a topic that was opened in 2016 on this issue: [retrieve-ttl-of-pojo-stored-using-spring-redis-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920986/retrieve-ttl-of-pojo-stored-using-spring-redis-repository)

In response, an issue was created: [Read back actual TTL into TimeToLive property. [DATAREDIS-523]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/1099)

As I understand it, this has already been dealt with.

And if I refer to the Redis documentation: [spring-data/redis/time-to-live](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/reference/redis/redis-repositories/expirations.html), using the @TimeToLive annotation should return the remaining lifetime of my entity: `@TimeToLive reads back the actual TTL or PTTL value from Redis.`

However, when I use it, I always get the same duration, the initial duration.

Here's my Kotlin code:

```kotlin
@RedisHash("AccessToken")
class AccessToken(
    @Id
    var id: String?,
    @Indexed
    var token: String,
    override var clientId: String,
    override var userId: String,
    @TimeToLive(unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    var timeToLive: Long,
    var scope: ScopeEnum?
): AbstractRelatedInfos()
```

Have I got it wrong? How do I retrieve the actual TTL?